# How to use Redux-Persist with Next.js App Router

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux, next.js13, redux-persist

I followed the official docs in how to make the redux work with Next.js app router. Everything worked as expected, but now I am trying to persist the data with `redux-persist` and things got very muddy.

There is no example in the official redux docs. I don't know how to deal with the fact that I am creating a Redux store per request by using `configureStore` wrapped in a `makeStore` function (recommended approach by official Redux docs to use Redux with Next app router).

I can't even pass `makeStore` to the `persistStore` method without getting type errors:

> ```
> Argument of type '() => EnhancedStore<{ user:
> userInterface; } & PersistPartial, UnknownAction,
> Tuple<[StoreEnhancer<{ dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{ user: userInterface;
> } & PersistPartial, undefined, UnknownAction>; }>, StoreEnhancer]>>'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'Store<any, UnknownAction,
> unknown>'
> ```

This is where I am currently at:

store.js:

```js
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {userReducer} from "./user/userSlice"

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      whitelist: ['user'],
  },
  combinedReducers
)

export const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        }),
  })
}

export const persistor = persistStore(makeStore)

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch']
```

store provider:

```
"use client";

import { useRef } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { makeStore, AppStore } from "../redux/store";

export default function StoreProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }

  return <Provider store={storeRef.current}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

layout.js

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import StoreProvider from "./StoreProvider";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "App",
  description: "App Desription",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <StoreProvider>{children}</StoreProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

How can I adapt the code to persist the Redux data considering the necessity of creating the store per request?

Answer (score 4):

Below is my implentation of the `store.ts`

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import userSlice from './features/login/userSlice'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'persist',
  storage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userSlice,
})

const makeConfiguredStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
  })

export const makeStore = () => {
  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
  if (isServer) {
    return makeConfiguredStore()
  } else {
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
    let store: any = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
    })
    store.__persistor = persistStore(store)
    return store
  }
}

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch']
```

We need to know of the server and client mode in Next.js because we don't eventually need persistence on the server side.

Below is my implementation of `StoreProvider.tsx`

```
'use client'

import { useRef } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { makeStore, AppStore } from '../lib/store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

export default function StoreProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>()
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore()
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current.__persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Using ref to maintain the `store` state between renders, you can then wrap your whole app with this `StateProvider` component.

A huge shout-out to this blog [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/use-redux-next-js/) for making it look easier.

Comment: This basically resolving noop storage issue and able to see data updation in localstorage. but not consistent. sometimes., when we stop and restart app., persist is not getting created. Not sure why